# WPF MediaElement, how to make repeat slower?

Tags: wpf

Delay on every repeat.

```
let mediaTimeline=MediaTimeline(Source=Uri@"...mp3",RepeatBehavior=RepeatBehavior.Forever)
let storyboard=Storyboard()
storyboard.Children.Add mediaTimeline
let mediaElement=MediaElement()
mediaElement.BeginStoryboard<|storyboard
```

(Answer in any language or WPF markup is welcome)

Comment: What do you mean by the delay? A pause before the song is played again?

Comment: looks like F# to me, as well... just saying

Comment: Yes, pause a second before play again. @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

MediaElement me = new MediaElement(); // Make sure add this control to Window or a control.

me.MediaEnded += me_MediaEnded;
me.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;  // Must have this line
// load song...
me.Play();


async void me_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    me.Play();
}
```

Note: `await` require `.Net 4.5`. If your .Net verstion is lower, you can use `DispatcherTimer` instead.

Comment: why it won't complie? Is there an error? My app complie with no problem.

Comment: @Sakure maybe its with c# version; i'm using 4.0... whatever the idea is correct.

Comment: Ah yes, it is `await` feature of `4.5`